# failed to open stream: No such file or directory (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, controller

I renamed my `UsersController.php` file to `~UsersController.php` for testing purposes and everything was working fine until I renamed it back to `UsersController.php` and now I'm getting the below error

> `include(C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/~UsersController.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

i'm getting the above error when I want submit form to `UsersController` while I didn't change anything in my route file or views.

Comment: Try `php artisan config:cache` `php artisan config:clear`  `composer dump-autoload -o`

Comment: Can I add as answer?

Comment: @VaheShak sure, you can post it as answer. I will vote +1

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try
`php artisan config:clear &&  composer dump-autoload -o`

Comment: The error happened to me after I renamed a Controller. This answer fixed it.

Comment: php artisan config:clear isn't needed config:cache will do it before:
Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!

Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!

Comment: @vahe-shak What is the differences between `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan config:clear`, and `composer dump-autoload -o`?

Comment: Could you update the asnwer to explain what each command does. 

Laravel specifies ```You should typically run the php artisan config:cache command as part of your production deployment process. The command should not be run during local development as configuration options will frequently need to be changed during the course of your application's development.``` 

Without explanation people might run your code blindly with consequences.

Comment: I suggest running `config:clear` first if youre on development and then trying to see if it works

Comment: Thank you, this still works on Laravel 10

Answer (score 4):

Use the command for autoload -o old files and generate new files in existing project

```
"composer dump-autoload -o"
```

This will autoload files

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was with the autoloader loading old deleted files so I just used  " composer dump-autoload -o " and it worked

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was from the internal repository it reads the old path so,
the solution is to use `composer update` to read the new repository path.

Answer (score 0):

use this code. 
You have to run `composer dumpautoload` inside your project folder.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was useful to use the command 'composer update', also you can use the command composer dump