# broken symbolic link in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-6

I create one form to upload profile pictures before with following code,

```js
 
        $image = $request->file('avatar');
        $pass = Hash::make($request->password);
    if($image!=null){

        $avatar_name = $request->get('NIC').'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $folder = '/uploads/avatars/';
       // $filePath = $folder . $avatar_name;
        $this->uploadOne($image, $folder, 'public', $avatar_name);

        DB::table('users')->insert([
            [
            'avatar_id' => $avatar_name, 
            
          .
          .
          .
          .
           public function uploadOne(UploadedFile $uploadedFile, $folder = null, $disk = 'public', $filename = null)
    {
        $name = !is_null($filename) ? $filename : Str::random(25);

        $path =storage_path('uploads/avatars/'.$filename.'');

        if( Storage::exists($path)){
          
         Storage::disk('public')->delete('uploads/avatars/'.$filename.'');  
        }
        $file = $uploadedFile->storeAs($folder, $name, $disk);
        return $file;
    }
```

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route('edit_user.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
                            @csrf
                            
                            
                            <div class="pl-lg-4">
                            <input type="text" name="user_id_" id="input-user_id" hidden>
                            <fieldset name="Personal_information">
                            <legend class="heading-small text-muted mb-4" >Personal information</legend>
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('avatar') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-avatar">{{ __('Avatar') }}</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="avatar" id="input-avatar" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('avatar') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" >

                                    @if ($errors->has('avatar'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('avatar') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
```

Then I made a symlink using artisan command "php artisan storage: link"
And it works fine.

Now I make another page to upload some documents with following code,

```js
$id = auth()->id();
        $timestamp_=now()->toDateTimeString();
        $doc = $request->file('leave_document');
        if($doc!=null){
            $leave_doc_name = $id.'_'.$timestamp_.'.'.$doc->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $folder = '/uploads/leave_documents/';
            $filePath = $folder . $leave_doc_name;
            $this->uploadOne($doc, $folder, 'public', $leave_doc_name);
        }else{
            $leave_doc_name =null;
        }
        if($request->leave_id_=="add"){
      
        DB::table('leave_requests')->insert([
            [
                'document_id'=>$leave_doc_name,
                
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                
    public function uploadOne(UploadedFile $uploadedFile, $folder = null, $disk = 'public', $filename = null)
    {
        $name = !is_null($filename) ? $filename : Str::random(25);

        $path =storage_path('uploads/leave_documents/'.$filename.'');

        if( Storage::exists($path)){
          
         Storage::disk('public')->delete('uploads/leave_documents/'.$filename.'');  
        }
        $file = $uploadedFile->storeAs($folder, $name, $disk);
        return $file;
    }
```

```html
<form id="addEventForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('leave.store') }}" autocomplete="off">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="pl-lg-4">
                            <input type="text" name="leave_id_" id="input-leave_id" hidden>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('leave_document') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-leave_document">{{ __('Document') }}</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="leave_document" id="input-leave_document" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('leave_document') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" >
                                </div>
```

As you can see both codes are the same. The only major difference is the storage folders.
(first one user  "\storage\app\public\uploads\avatars" folder and second one uses "storage\app\public\uploads\leave_documents" folder.

but for the second one, I get an error saying

> fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\ACCHE_HR\storage\app/public\uploads/leave_documents/2_2020-03-15 19:31:14.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

So it seems symlink only work for avatar folder
I try to remove symlink using "rm public/storage" command and it also gives me the following error,

> rm : C:\xampp\htdocs\ACCHE_HR\public\storage is an NTFS junction point. Use the Force parameter to delete or modify this object.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + rm public/storage
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\xampp\htdocs\ACCHE_HR\public\storage:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotEmpty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

and I search everywhere, also try to find a way to create custom symlinks and failed.
How do I resolve this problem, Also I'm new to Laravel?

Please Help!

Comment: is it the same solution as here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203254/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory-laravel Hope it helps

Comment: no,I just tried them.still doesn't working

Comment: well to remove the symlink use "rm -f public/storage" then maybe try again to create it, not sure sry

Comment: Remove-Item : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'f' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Filter 
-Force.
At line:1 char:4
+ rm -f public/storage
+    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: another error shows

Comment: "rm -Force public/storage" then I think

Comment: It works,I was able to remove symlink and recreate another one.But still No such file error shows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209674/discussion-between-rustyjim-and-naduni-warnakulasooriya).

Comment: are  you showing it in a view and it gives error or during saving your picture ?

Comment: No,I'm not showing it in a view yet

Answer (score 1):

When I change my file name to something like this

```
$leave_doc_name = 'abc.'.$doc->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

From

```
$leave_doc_name = $id.'_'.$timestamp_.'.'.$doc->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

It works.

It seems the timestamp function doesn't work with the file upload.